# PHP mkdir permissione denied only with a scheduled task

Tags: php, apache, permissions, mkdir

```
$old = umask(0);
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/'.$ID.'/', 0755, true);
umask($old);
```

Running this lines from browser works fine, instead if I run this script via a scheduled task, it gives:

> 'mkdir(): Permission denied'.

Version Plesk Onyx v17.0.17_build1700161028.14 os_CentOS 7

OS  CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 (Core)

nginx   1.11.10-centos7.17102311

php 5.4.16-43.el7_4

Comment: As what user is this code running in the two cases? What is the ownership on the according paths?

Comment: According to echo `whoami`; it's the same user, so I suppose it's the same ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the script is executed via a browser, domain PHP handler with the corresponding configuration is used.
Scheduled PHP task is running using system PHP handler, therefore PHP configuration for the domain is ignored and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable does not give the same result.
Try using `Run a command` scheduled task type, using full path for required PHP binary and corresponding `php.ini`. For PHP 7.0 shipped with Plesk and PHP configuration for `example.com` domain:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -c /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/etc/php.ini /path/to/script.php
```

The same but for system PHP:

```
/bin/php -c /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/etc/php.ini /path/to/script.php
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Yesterday I finally managed to fix it after hours of struggling... thank you.